# How to get sum of same field for ALL user_id from a pivot dataframe indexed by two fields 'timestamps' and 'user_id'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table below contained in the DataFrame pivoted below :

```
        cost        cost        cost        val1        val1        val1    
user_id     1       2       3       1       2       3   
timestamp
01/01/2011      1               100     3               5   
01/02/2011              20  8           
01/07/2012      19  57                  
01/11/2012  3100    49  
21/12/2012              240 30          
14/09/2013      21  63                  
01/12/2013  3200    51
```

I would like to know how I can obtain another dataframe containing only the sum of all same fields for all users id (e.g. sum of the fields 'cost' for user 1, 2 and 3).

The code use in order to obtain the above table is :

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['timestamp','user_id', 'cost', 'val1','val2', 'val3','code']
df = pd.read_csv('mytest.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True) 
pivoted = df.pivot('timestamp', 'user_id')
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the original dataframe (`df`) to test so I can't be sure, but I would use a goupby on `df` and not manipulate your dataframe, `pivoted`:

```
df.groupby('user_id')[['cost', 'val1','val2', 'val3']].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks.I will equally order them by timestamps.